# Problems getting inputted values from forms in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hey guys, this is my first time using jQuery. I'm working on a simple Twitter app that checks whether a user is following another user, but I'm having trouble picking up on the inputted values in my form.

I've got this form on my page:

```
<form id="form_friendship">
  Is <input type='text' name='user_a' value='username'/> following <input type='text' name='user_b' value='username'/> on Twitter? <input type="submit" value="Check">  
</form>
```

And using the form plugin, here's my JS:

```
var value = $('#form_friendship *').fieldValue( );
$('#form_friendship *').submit(alert(value));
```

The only thing that's being alerted is "username, username" and it's not registered text inputted into the fields at all. Any ideas on what's wrong here? Thanks

Comment: FYI, there's a "Code Sample" button above the edit area that looks like **`{ }`**. To format your code, highlight the code, and click that button. I took care of it for you on this question.

Comment: Maybe because the default value of both input are 'username'?

Comment: OK, a few things wrong with this. First of all, `value` is an array. You probably want an object (map) of key-value pairs. Secondly, `alert` doesn't return anything. Not even sure why it's in there. Thirdly, your form doesn't go anywhere. I have no idea how your server side works, but either your form needs a destination (the `action` attribute), or you should be using AJAX to send the data and get a response. The jQuery Form plugin, which you appear to be using, will do the client side of this for you.

Comment: @patrick dw - thanks for the heads up patrick! appreciate it. @sheavi - no sheavi, that's not why. @samir - this doesn't help at all samir. i'm obviously not alerting for the sake of alerting. i'm doing it to find out how to pull the values via jquery form plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that your javascript should look more like this

```
var userA = $('input[name:user_a]').val(),
userB = $('input[name:user_b]').val( );

$('#form_friendship').submit(function(){
    alert(userA +', '+userB);
});
```

if you want to collect all the values from the form with out specifying the actual input you can try something like

```
$('#form_friendship').submit(function(){

    //creating array to put values
    var inputs = [];

    //loop to catch all inputs type=text
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        //pushing values into array
        inputs.push($(this).val());
    })

    //joining alerting values in array
    alert(inputs.join(', '));



});
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what's wrong with your's but i link them both up as below and it works for me.

```
 <html class="ui-widget-content" lang="en_US"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Form Plugin</title>
<style type="text/css">
form { background: #DFEFFC; border: 5px solid #c5dbec; margin: 10px 0; padding: 20px }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/malsup/form/raw/master/jquery.form.js?v2.43"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $('#form_friendship *').fieldValue();
    $('#form_friendship').submit(function(){
        alert(value);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form_friendship">
  Is <input type='text' name='user_a' value='jack'/> following <input type='text' name='user_b' value='username'/> on Twitter? <input type="submit" value="Check">  
</form>
</body></html>
```

think the * after your form id is messing with the submit.
this line:

```
$('#form_friendship').submit(function()
```

Comment: if you try entering the values with that code and clicking on check, the inputted values still don't get alerted